# Generic Editor Template

Tags: c#, generics, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, system.reflection

Is it possible to create a generic view with `System.Reflection` ?
 
So I could `loop` throught the `class properties` creating `inputs` with the `@Html.EditorFor` or `@Html.Editor` or even a normal `<input />`.
 
With this I could create a `template` and re-use it to save time and create a pleasant image to the users.

So is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, the model of the view should be object, and the controller can be an generic controller, but you should build your own ControllerControllerFactory like:

```
    public class MyGenericControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext reqContext, string controllerName)
        {
            if(is controlleName generic) //you should define how build controller name when is generic
            //it should contain the controller name and the generic type name
            {
                string contRealName = "";//get the real controller name from controllerName var
                string genTypeName = ""; //get the generic type name fomr controllerName var
                Type contType = Type.GetType(contRealName);
                Type genType = Type.GetType(genTypeName);
                contType = contType.MakeGenericType(genType);
                return an instance of contType from your IoC container
            }
            else
            {
                Type contType = Type.GetType(controllerName);
                return an instance of contType from your IoC container
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used your answer and other things, i create a `.cshtml ` file or replace it, then i loop throught the  `properties ` , if the property lead me to a  `recursive loop ` i ignore it, if it is a implementation of  `IEnumerable<T> `, i apend a  `@Html.DropdownList(propName)` and add a  `ViewBag ` to the  `ViewContext` with a auto generated linq query using AI, its like a big generic  `StringBuilder` to generate and read a  `.cshtml` file